# $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=0 \implies a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, problem-solving

How to prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2$ given that $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=0$?

Comment: It will be better if you show at least some of your work or whatever you have attempted ... that way people would be more likely to answer your questions

Answer (score 24):

Expand the right side:

$$(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2ab + 2ac + 2bc.$$

From the supplementary condition we have

$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} = 0$$

*Or*

$$\frac{ab+ac+bc}{abc} = 0.$$

Therefore $ab+ac+bc = 0$ and the result follows. (None of $a,b,c$ can be $0$ else their inverses would be undefined and so the supplementary condition would be ill-posed.)

Answer (score 7):

$(a+b+c)^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+2ab+2ac+2bc=a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+2abc\big(\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a}\big)=a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$

since $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=0$.